# Hide X axis labels in a CCC line chart

Tags: reporting, pentaho, protovis, pentaho-ctools

Using Ctools through the Pentaho User Console/BI Server I'm wanting to keep the label Title on the x-axis (base axis) but hide the x-axis labels for my CCC Bar Chart component.  When selecting baseAxisVisible to False in the Advanced properties it hides both.

Is there a way to manipulate this through an extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the axis visible, you can hide the tick-labels using:

baseAxisLabel_visible: false

Comment: Ive tried that option but when set to false it hides the base Axis Title as well.  On my base axis I have a list of projects.  I don't want these project names to be visible on the axis but I need the base axis title to remain visible.